# Which CEP platform is most popular for trading systems?

Tags: trading, trading-systems, order-handling, order-execution, cep

I heard that trading firms employ CEP platforms such as StreamBase, Marketcetera, JBoss Drools, and etc., to implement trading systems. I wonder which one is most popular and the recent trend of related technology.

Comment: We're trying to [avoid surveys during the beta](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4/please-avoid-surveys-polls-subjective-questions-and-very-broad-questions-durin). Also, Marketcetera isn't a CEP; it uses [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/).

Comment: CEP is certainly on-topic, but I agree with @chrisaycock: this question isn't appropriate for the site.  There is no way to answer which is the most popular, especially when you start to include things like open source solutions.

Comment: Have a look at [AlgoTrader](http://www.algotrader.ch). It is based on Esper. There is a free Open Source Version and a commercial Enterprise Version.